# How to check the client browser performance with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, canvas, p5.js

I'm building a website and in one part of the website, there is a canvas. Every time I scroll at that viewport, the browser gets laggy. I want to check the browser performance, for example, an "FPS" and with JavaScript make a function with a condition that if the fps is below 50 it won't display the canvas.

If you want more information: I'm using p5.js and I tried my best for improving the code for performance.

I'm using Vue.js.

And that's basically it.

Is there a way to check the browser performance?

Comment: You can use `requestAnimationFrame()` and time it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using p5.js, then it sounds like you're looking for the `frameRate()` function.

You can find more info in the [reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/frameRate), but in summary you probably want to do something like this:

```js
function draw(){
  background(0);
  text(frameRate(), 100, 100);
}
```